# Can't install any OS on "old" PC

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp, boot, windows-server-2008

I got an old PC (I think bought in 2002) just for some experiments. It has still windows XP Professional SP2 so I wanted at first install windows server 2008 (because I got it form DreamSpark) but that didn't work so I tried Xubuntu that didn't work because of a syslinux/isolinux error. Then I tried Ubuntu --> same error. Windows 7 USB didn't even boot. A XP recovery CD also didn't boot.

Then I did a BIOS reset and now it directly boots into windows xp  it ignores the CDs and USBs also when I manualy choose them.

Can someone help me?

EDIT:
Here is the msinfo32 export: http://pastebin.com/4jqXQR6F

Comment: Without further (hardware) details, we cannot help you. Generally, the optical drive could simply be broken.

Comment: @DanielB I used a USB flash drive, I only used for XP recovery disk a CD. And the PC has two drives and I tried both.

Comment: With a PC that old, you won’t be able to boot from USB. No surprises there.

Comment: @DanielB So why can I select it in the boot menu?

Comment: You might want to try non-PAE versions of Linux on a machine that old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the drive worked normally in windows I thought the optical drive couldn't be the issue. But after I changed the drive it worked.

-->For other users experiencing this problem just try a different optical drive. (Also when it works normally in windows)

Answer (score 3):

Lets calm down..

Probaly your CPU isn't 64 bits.

So first check if your windows 7 and ubuntu are for 32 bits

When you reset your bios you desordered the Boot  device priority.

go to your Bios. search for Boot options, boot order and READ how to place your USB or DVD , etc on top.
save ( commonly F10) and exit

Archlinux comes with dual architecture support so you can try they live cd

and please comment if you get lucky !

Comment: Yeah the Windows 7 Version is 64-Bit my fault but Windows XP and (X)Ubuntu are for sure 32-Bit. I already changed the Boot order. Now I'll try this archlinux method. Thank you :)